# How to set Doctrine Auto Increment Starting Value @ORM\GeneratedValue[starts with 100] using symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

How can I set the starting value for an Auto Incremented like 100,101....
My code is

```
/**
 * @ORM\Name
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
 * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="name", initialValue=100)
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $name;
```

while trying i am getting an error like this

```
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Name" in property 
Epita\CrmBundle\Entity\CandidateAnalysisCrm::$name does not exist, or could 
not be auto-loaded.
```

please help me anyone. Thanks for advance

My entity is:

```
namespace Epita\CrmBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

 /**
  * category
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="candidateanalysiscrm")
  * @ORM\Entity
  */
  class CandidateAnalysisCrm {
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type = "integer", name= "id")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
public $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="applicationinprogress",length=10, 
 nullable=true) 
 */
protected $applicationinprogress;
/**
 * @ORM\Name
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
 * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="name", initialValue=100)
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="integer")
 */
protected $name;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues here:

First, as already mentioned there is no `@Name` [doctrine annotation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html).

Second, the `GeneratedValue` [annotation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#generatedvalue) only applies if your attribute is annotated with the `@Id` [annotation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-id).

From the documentation

> Specifies which strategy is used for identifier generation for an instance variable which is annotated by @Id. This annotation is optional and only has meaning when used in conjunction with @Id.
>
> If this annotation is not specified with @Id the NONE strategy is used as default.

To fix it change your `$name` attributes annotations to:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
 * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="name", initialValue=100)
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="integer")
 */
protected $name;
}
```

If using the `$name` property as identifier is not an option for you, listening to [doctrine events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) (e.g. `prePersist`) could be an alternative solution for your problem. But this is a totally different question.

Comment: Thank you so much your support

Comment: Finally i realize, this one is not supported in mysql any way thanks for your valuable support

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure, but i think that ORM\Name doesn't exist.

You have to write :

```
* @ORM\Column(name="column_name", type="string")
```

Comment: Can you see above post my entity class is to long i pasted some fields